# How do I make Jquery-UI button control-group highlight selected item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I got a problem with getting my buttons to keep showing the selected element. It only highlights when in focus. If I change focus to another element on the page, the selection disappears?

html:

```
  <div id="button-set" class="controlgroup">
      <button class="buttongroup" id="button-1"></button>
      <button  class="buttongroup" id="button-2"></button>
      <button  class="buttongroup" id="button-3"></button>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( ".controlgroup" ).controlgroup();
$( "#button-1" ).button({
           icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-file-image"
           },
           text: false
        });
$( "#button-2" ).button({
           icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-play"
           },
           text: false
        });
$( "#button-3" ).button({
        icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-locked"
           },
           text: false
});
```

**EDIT 1**

Before i posted this question i tried this fiddle with radiobuttons but couldn't get the icon-styling working: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/Gr4h3/ 
Now i realize that it's because it doesn't work for jquery-ui versions past 1.11.4. 
And yes! - i should have tried solve that puzzle before posting for this "controlgroup" solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question and similar answer: [how to set jquery button active state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665348/how-to-set-jquery-button-active-state)

When you hover over a button, or give it focus, the class `ui-state-active` is added. So if you want this state to persist, to indicate that a button is toggle on, you could do the same thing.

```
$( "#button-2" ).button({
  icons: {
    primary: "ui-icon-play"
  },
  text: false
}).click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")){
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-active");
  }
  // Your code here
});
```

You can use `ui-state-active` or `ui-state-focus`. Your choice.

Comment: I thought the controlgroup had a built-in function to link the buttons with only one selected at a time!? I'm wondering, do i need to use radiobuttons [input] for that functionality ?

Comment: I suspect so, since `button` is just click, where as `radio` or `check` would be yes/no style action.